# How to persist cookies in ios (objective c)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, nsurlconnection

How to persist cookies returned as a response of NSURLConnection ?
The cookies contains sessions.

This is the code i am using to create a connection -

```
Constants *constants = [[Constants alloc] init];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:constants.myURL]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *requestBodyData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.myConnection = conn;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to persist the cookies by yourself. `NSHTTPCookieStorage` will persist the cookies by itself but the cookies must have an expiry date set on the server-side. Otherwise it will be treated as 'session only' and will be cleared while restarting the app.

For setting cookie:

```
NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieProperties setObject:name forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:strValue forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"test.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];    
[cookieProperties setObject:@"test.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];


[cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:604800] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires]; // It'll set a expiry date of 1 week

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

In the above code without an expiry date your cookie will be cleared as soon as the app exits. If you want this kind of behavior then skip that line.

For getting back the cookie:

```
NSArray *httpCookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:httpUrl];
```

Read [the doc for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/).

Comment: The cookies i get from server has an expiry date set, but still cookies aren't saved.
What can i do ?

Comment: @Ashish > You are not saving it. Try saving the cookie.

Comment: how you can save? @Rashad